# Live Data Visualisation

Tags: data-visualization

I want to know if there is a simpler and quicker way to visualize dynamic data. The setup that I require is:

1. An admin web-interface with forms to feed data.
2. A public web-page with a table and few charts to display data dynamically.
3. Live and dynamic display of data.

I know python and I am currently learning django framework.

Solutions which don't require programming skills are also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Any CMS;
2. Take a look at google's [visualization api](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/using_overview.html).

Answer (score 2):

Visualizing the data client-side requires the use of something along the lines of [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) or [jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/), which you can customize to your specific scenario. You can, however, opt to display charts using images and generate them on the server, then switch the images periodically in Javascript.

The other technical hurdle is the way you get data on the client. Typically, you can implement polling via AJAX (easier) or some push mechanism (Comet, for example, though harder and requires server-side specifics). When you get the data on the client, you simply change out the data on the chart or remove and recreate it. When using images, it is as simple as changing the `src` property on the images, but requires generating the images on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts provides some really good examples.
[Realtime Plot Highcharts](http://jsfiddle.net/theo/2JvF9/)

Mostly AJAX shall suffice,but in case you wish to have a tightly coupled system,using [Django-chartit](http://chartit.shutupandship.com/) might also be an option

Answer (score 1):

When I setout to something very similar, I found these very useful,

1. [Admin theme](https://wrapbootstrap.com/themes/admin) : Look at these themes and relatively very inexpensive. Big time savers.
2. These themes already has some built-in graphs/charts. If you want something more complex, [D3 JS](http://d3js.org) impressed me. Also look at kendoUI and sencha UI charts.

You can ofcourse build your portal on django but I'm developing on ruby on rails. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you need live data visualization,the best solution is  Google Public Data Explorer  http://goo.gl/CWbxO . But first of all ,you should learn about DSPL https://developers.google.com/public-data/overview  ,the Dataset Publishing Language describes how your data is organized and how you want to show your data(e.g,bar chart ,line chart ,bubble char or else)

1. you can upload your data via http://www.google.com/publicdata/admin to upload your dataset
2. after you successfully upload your data,open it in your Public data adamin,explore the data,and you can get a link on the right ,you can embed the chart in your own website too
3. the chart is ilve,you can find some examples first,mostly,the x axis is by year,and you can describe it yourself

Here is a example of Google Public Data Explorer.  http://goo.gl/yZ5Cj